# Get coordinates of touch event in Android emulator externally

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-view

I want to have a real-time record of the pixel xy coordinates of touches made on the Android emulator that is application-independent and is available to programs outside of the emulator (perhaps an updating text file or stream). I know about `MotionEvent` but that would not be application-independent (requires editing the code of any app that would be used).

Basically, I want the functionality of the `Dev Tools/Development Settings/Pointer Location` function on the emulator, that would record the latest touch event and can send that coordinate information external of the emulator.

Is there anyway that I might accomplish this?